Syntactic representation of a compound word
I want to create a syntactic representation of a compound word "стакан воды". Here, "стакан" is in the nominative and "воды" is in the genitive. Both nouns also have no prepositions (like "of" of English), as their morphosyntactic information is indicated through inflection.
How can we represent the words through syntactic tree?
Is it

Two nouns under a noun phrase



A noun an a determiner phrase under a N-bar


Or is there any alternative syntactic representation for this compound word?

A compound word is one word, but there are two words in “стакан воды” which is a noun phrase. You can see that it's not one word by the fact that you can freely insert other words in between the two, e.g.: “стакан чистой воды”, “стакан горячей воды”, “стакан этой воды”, “стакан моей воды”, etc.

Thank you for the information :) @YellowSky
